# Different margins for odd and even number pages

Tags: spacing, geometry

According to my institute guidelines Ii have to do the following in my thesis:

> - Left margin: 1.25" (to ensure sufficient space for binding), Right mar-
>     gin: 1"
> - Caution: For front and back printing, left and right depends on the
>     page number being odd or even. Therefore for the thesis which is
>     to be printed back and front, the margins of odd numbered pages
>     (=pages on right) are as above, while for the even numbered pages
>     (=pages on left) the left margin should be 1" and right margin
>     should be 1.25".

I used this in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{epsfig,epic,eepic,units}
\usepackage[inner=1.25cm,outer=1cm,bottom=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
```

But this is keeping 1.25" space on left on even number pages too. How can I keep odd number pages at 1.25" on left and 1" on right but vica versa for even numbered pages?

Comment: Set the left and right margin to 1inch and use the option `bindingoffset=0,25in`

Comment: Add option `showframe` to the call of geometry to better see what left and right hand pages are.

Comment: Without a minimal working example, we cannot varify that your document is faulty and rely on you stating it. Not a good way to propose a solution.

Comment: I looked at your other questions, TeXmaker and overleaf are just editors and have nothing to do with any error messages LaTeX gives you.

Comment: You should add the `twoside` option to the `\documentclass` command: the `report` class uses `oneside` by default.  You should better do so even if your margins were symmetric.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti When I tried '\documentclass[twoside][12pt]{report}', It says '.cls not found. !!

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth - The proper syntax is `\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{report}`. Note that the options are (i) contained in a *single* pair of square brackets and (ii) separated by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following setup:

```
\documentclass[twoside, <further options>]{report}
\usepackage[inner=1.25in, outer=1in, vmargin=2in]{geometry}
```

where `<further options>` might include `12pt`.

Note that whereas the instructions appear to be phrased as using inches as the main unit of length, your code appears to be using centimeters as the unit of length. Do clarify with your school which length unit applies.

Comment: I want inches... How do I change that?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth - Please look at the code in my answer: it uses `in` rather than `cm` as the unit of length. Doe this answer your question?

Comment: I ll let you know once I ll run this. Thanks.

Comment: it works but what is the purpose of \vmargin can you tell?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth - `vmargin=2in` is more concise than `bottom=2in,top=2in`.

Comment: Thanks. It is better too,as vmargin=1in is working fine in my case but top and bottom=1in was eating up the bottom numbering. Many Thanks